# Why cannot the vector $v = (1,2)$ span entire $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So in my knowledge $\mathbb{R}^2$ can generate points and lines.

So the span of vector $v$ would be $\text{span}(v) = c(1,2)$.This would generate all the lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for different real values of $c$.

So shouldn't this span the entire Vector Space $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Also in some sources I read,it says the the vector $v$ only spans the line $y = -x/2$ and not the entire $2D$ space.

Doesnt the entire space of R2 contains only points and lines?

EDIT:I made the necessary edits as suggested and gave explanations when asked in the comments.If there is any other thing I need to do, please tell me before downvoting.I also thank the contributors for helping me out.

Comment: One vector can only span *one* line in $\Bbb R^2$, because "span" means by definition all $\lambda\cdot v$ with $\lambda \in K$. And indeed, take any different vector, e.g., $w=(1,1)$. Of course $w=\lambda v$ is impossible, because $(1,1)=(\lambda,2\lambda)$ has no solution.

Comment: How do you write $(2,3)$ as $c(1,2) = (c,2c)$?

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 isnt defination of span for vectors as span(v) = c*v?

Comment: @SavannahMadison yes, precisely, where $c$ is a scalar

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 yeah isn't mentioning real value suffecient?

Comment: @SavannahMadison I don't get what you mean, sorry. The bottom line here is that you cannot write every vector as a scalar multiple of $v$ - for instance, $(2,3)$ or $(1,1)$ cannot be written as $c(1,2)$.

Comment: But I still don't get the notion of entire space of R2 geometrically.

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 span(v1,v2) = c1(2,3) + c2(1,1) for real values of c1 and c2.Is this not possible?

Comment: @SavannahMadison yes, those two vectors generate $\mathbb{R}^2$, but what does that have to do with the original question?

Comment: Why the downvotes? OP was confused and contributors are helping

Comment: I made the necessary edits as suggested and gave explanations when asked in the comments.If there is any other thing I need to do, please tell me before downvoting.I also thank the contributors for helping me out.

Comment: What is the meaning of "So in my knowledge $\Bbb R^2$ can generate points and lines." ?

Comment: @Brozovic I meant R2 would span points and lines in my knowledge. Not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim

```
So the span of vector v would be span(v) = c(1,2).
This would generate all the lines in R2 for different real values of c.
```

is false.

$\vec v$ will span only the line $(c,2c)$ that is $y=2x$.

Maybe you are confusing with the equation of a line $y=mx$ (which anyway excludes the line $x=0$).

Comment: So it cannot span the any other line right?So hence it cannot span the entire R2?

Comment: No, it can't. Multiplying a vector by a constant just gives parallel vectors. Larger or shorter vectors. It can't change the direction of a vector @SavannahMadison

Comment: Thank you for taking out your time in explaining stuff to a beginner like me.!

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of $c$ for which $c\cdot (1,2)$ is equal to $(1,1)$?